# jQuery not register $

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using prototype + jquery on a site. Now the prototype plugins use $. I do not want jQuery to use $. How do I make jQuery not register the $. Also, how do I then call jQuery functions.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The jQuery [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) has an article on how to make jQuery play nice with other libraries.

This is one suggested way from that article:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="prototype.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery.noConflict();

    // Put all your code in your document ready area
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      // Do jQuery stuff using $
      $("div").hide();
    });

    // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
    $('someid').hide();
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. link jquery first and prototype  second. this will override the $.
2. for jQuery, use the function `jQuery(...)`.

Comment: I find that this is the best method for when you want to use jQuery throughout the page (situations such as onclick attributes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.noConflict( );` And then you can remap it like this: `$j = jQuery`;

Comment: or: var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 1):

this is what I use if it's only a small bit of jQuery

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // now you can use $ again within here - this block of code is fired on DOM ready

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's noConflict method:

```
var jQ=jQuery.noConflict();
```

now onwards you can use jQ in place of "$" to work with jQuery functions and use $ for prototype.